# React-redux connect function can't map state to props after multiple consecutive state changes using redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a simple reducer:

```js
// reducer.js
const itemId = (state = "", action) => {
  if (action.type === SET_ID) {
    console.log("reducer updated");
    return action.payload.id;
  }
  else {
    return state;
  }
};
```

A component *connected* to the store:

```
const Component = ({ itemId }) => {
  console.log("Component rendered");
  return <div> {itemId}</div>;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  itemId: state.itemId
});

export const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(Component);
```

And a saga with three actions, where the first and the last action have the same payload:

```js
const createSetIdAction = id => ({
  type: SET_ID,
  payload: {
    id
  }
});

export const saga = function*() {
  yield put(createSetIdAction("FirstID"));
  yield put(createSetIdAction("SecondID"));
  yield put(createSetIdAction("FirstID"));
};
```

When these actions are dispatched, the reducer is updated three times in a row, once per each action. This means that the state has changed and each connected component should reflect this change.

The problem is that my component is not being re-rendered three times as I'd expect. Perhaps because the `mapStateToProps` is too slow to notice a state change, or when it notices a state change, it contains the same value as before, thus doesn't render anything.

When I add a small delay (more than approximately 35ms in my browser), everything starts to work:

```
// saga
  yield put(createSetIdAction("First_ID"));
  yield delay(35);
  yield put(createSetIdAction("Second_ID"));
  yield put(createSetIdAction("First_ID"));
```

and the component renders as expected.

Is there a way how to make the connect function render the component after each state update, without using `delay` in the saga?

Working [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-northcutt-keniz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer.

React-Redux does not guarantee that your UI code will run for every single dispatched action.  It only guarantees that it will be run with the *latest* value from the store.

This is due to a combination of how React-Redux manages subscriptions to the store and propagates updates, as well as how React batches re-renders.